# Database errors if specific guild doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I have per guild settings on my discord bot. However, for some reason if the guild doesn't exist it errors. I have over 150 guilds that my bot is in, and this was only recently added. I don't know what to do to make it work ...

I have tried different methods of calling if the data is null but I always get an error and end up with this original chunk of code

```
client.updateGuild = async (guild, settings) => {
    let data = await client.getGuild(guild);

    if (typeof data !== 'object') data = {};
    for (const key in settings) {   
        if (data[key] !== settings[key]) data[key] = settings[key];
        else return;
    }

    console.log(`Guild "${data.guildName}" updated settings: ${Object.keys(settings)}`);
    return await data.updateOne(settings);
};
```

If the guild does not exist it should make a new entry for the guild and save the updated config settings when someone runs the config command

```
client.createGuild = async settings => {
        const defaults = Object.assign({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId() }, client.config.defaultSettings);
        const merged = Object.assign(defaults, settings);

        const newGuild = await new Guild(merged);
        return newGuild.save()
            .then(console.log(`Default settings saved for guild "${merged.guildName}" (${merged.guildID})`));
    };
```

This is the command run when it is added to a guild after the update, but like I said theres over 150 old ones ;-;

Comment: Have you tried to add in options of `updateOne` `{upsert:true}` ?
According to `mongoose` docs (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne) it's `false` by default and it allows to create new doc in DB, if it isn't exist.

Comment: no I have not. I didnt even see that. I will try it now!

Comment: ```(node:19704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: data.updateOne is not a function```

Comment: return await data.updateOne(settings, {upsert:true});

Comment: I need it to run client.createGuild with the settings from that ^^'

Comment: Yeah. So does it worked? Remember, that there are 3 args in `updateOne` Actually in my own opinion it's better to use `findAndUpdate` queries, instead of `updateOne` and trigger `.save()`

Comment: no, it didnt ^^'

Comment: what is in `console.log(settings)` output before `return await data.updateOne(settings);` in your scenario?

Comment: ```{ prefix: '()' }
Guild "undefined" updated settings: prefix
(node:8904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: data.updateOne is not a function```

running the eval command to manually add the guild to the db gives a name and doesnt give an error. I need the updateGuild function to run the createGuild function if there is no database entry ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, the problem is somewhere here:
`return await data.updateOne(settings);`

1. `data` should be an actual `collection/model` and according to `let data = await client.getGuild(guild);` it should return a model, but I'm 99% sure that it's not. Well, I don't see what `client.getGuild` does, so.. that's why I'm sure only for 99%
2. The second vector of the problem lies here, `settings` object should be equal to these schema: `{filter_field: value},{update_field: value},{upsert:true}` and as a result:

```
... = await model_name.updateOne({filter: value},{update: field},{upsert:true}).exec(callback)
```

And for the more, if you want to:

> I need the `updateGuild` function to run the `createGuild` function if there is no database entry

I guess that `updateGuild` inside, should looks like this, w/o `createGuild` method:

```
let result = await model_name.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                fieldName: filterValue,
            },
            new Class(object),
            {
                upsert : true,
                new: true,
                setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
                runValidators: true,
                lean: true
            }
        ).exec();
```

in that case, `result` variable have updated docs data, and some values could be displayed to the user of the bot, via destructive method if it succeeded. 
Or trigger `await createGuild();` directly, in `updateGuild` without upside code snippet if it allows to.

Comment: Sorry! The get guild is ```client.getGuild = async guild => {
        const data = await Guild.findOne({ guildID: guild.id });
        if (data) return data;
        else return client.config.defaultSettings;
    };```

Comment: That's it. Now I can literally confirm that first scenario is in place, because if there is no `guild` in your database, the `getGuild` gets to `else` exception where `data` becomes not a mongoose model. And that's why you receive an error at the `return await data.updateOne(settings);` string. To be honest, I highly recommend you to re-write that part of code, but I guess it's a part of `class` as a `getter/setter` so probably it's not an option.

Comment: I am not sure how to rewrite that part without rewriting the entire code but this does explain some of the other issues I have been having!

Comment: Well, you don't have enough rep on SW to chat with me, what's your discord.tag then? Or probably you want to write me a message and i'll explain something about it. My tag is `AlexZeDim#2812` And, yes I have a default green avatar.